Adding a custom style to vuetify table header
I am trying to apply a custom style to v-data header through the use of a fixHeader method.
The CSS basically tries to fix the header in place, even if you scroll to the right.
The problem is that the style is applied to the internal <span> element inside the outer <<th>> and so it fixes the header relative to the th. What I need is for this dynamic style to be applied to the outer th instead of the span inside so that it fixes the header relative to the entire row of headers.
<template>
  <v-data-table
    dense
    :headers="listAttrs"
    :items="list"
    >
      <template v-for="(col, i) in fixedColumns" v-slot:[`header.${col.value}`]="{ header }">
       <span :style="fixHeader(col.value)"  >{{ col.text }}</span>
      </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  fixHeader(key) {        
    let offset = 0
    let index = this.listAttrs.findIndex(el => el.value === key)
    let col = this.listAttrs[index]
    let fixed = col?.fixed

    for (let x = 0 ;  x < index ; x++ ) {
      offset += Number(this.listAttrs[x].width)
      console.log("SPEC:: ", col)
      console.log("FIXED:: ", fixed)
      console.log("offset:: ", offset)
    
      if(this.fixedColumns[this.fixedColumns.length - 1].value === key)
        return {
          left: offset+'px', position: 'sticky !important',background: 'white',boxShadow: 'inset -7px 0 9px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',  
        } else if(fixed) {
          console.log("FIX HEADER!!")
          return {left: offset+'px', position: 'sticky !important', background: 'white', 
        }
     }
  }  
</script>

Image of parsed HTML code:

I know that you can set a class property in the headers array like so and define a class that will be applied to the th like so
headers: [
  { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', class:'fixed1' },
  { text: 'Inst',value: 'inst',class:'fixed2' },
]

But this won't work for me because you can only pass it in fixed classes, and I need to pass it in a dynamic style that has the left property modified based on a function.
Additionally I know that you can hide the defaul header using the prop hide-default-header and overwrite the entire headers with your own using
 <template v-slot:header="{ props }">
    <th v-for="header in listAttrs" :style="fixCol(header.value)">
      {{header.text}}
      </th>
  </template>

But I need to keep the sorting functionality provided by the default Header, which is lost when you overwrite with your own. So perhaps there is a a way to implement the code above AND keep the sorting capability?

Actually, you can use the class property in the headers, and define headers as computed property to return the dynamic values.

Since it's a compute property, it will return the dynamic value you wanted.

but the computed eventually has to return a fixed class right? I mean sure I can define a bunch of classes like fixed1 fixed2 fixed3 that has the modified left property, but I want to make it dynamic so that I dont have to define a bunch of classes for each column I want be fixed position

You can define the headers as a computed property to return dynamic values based on the conditions.
computed: {
    headers(){
      ...
    }
}

Check the example for detail information: https://codepen.io/ramseyfeng/pen/NWVgKBm
